# Routing for executing different GET methods with same type of parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Could anybody little help me with routing?

In **WebApiConfig** I have this mapping

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{uid}",
    defaults: new {uid = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

and two methods in controller

```
[RoutePrefix("AppartmentCategory")]
public class AppartmentCategoryController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid uid){...}

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{propertyUid?}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetList(Guid propertyUid){...}
}
```

When I try to send requests

```
1. http://.../AppartmentCategory/043F61D1-7194-E611-A98B-9C5C8E0005FA
```

and

```
2. http://.../AppartmentCategory/?propertyUid=2fdc968d-0192-e611-a98b-9c5c8e0005fa
```

In both cases executing method **public IHttpActionResult GetList(Guid propertyUid)**

What shold I fix for executing **public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid uid)** method for first request?

Comment: You are mixing convention-based routing and attribute routing. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` is mapped before convention routes (as it should) so it will hit the `GetLists` first. Technically both actions will have similar routes. You should try to differentiate the two actions a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing convention-based routing and attribute routing. `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` is mapped before convention-based routes (as it should)

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{uid}",
    defaults: new {uid = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

so it will hit the `GetLists` first as first match always win when matching templates. Technically both actions will have similar routes.

```
[RoutePrefix("AppartmentCategory")]
public class AppartmentCategoryController : ApiController
{
    //GET AppartmentCategory/043F61D1-7194-E611-A98B-9C5C8E0005FA VIA CONVENTION-BASED ROUTING
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid uid){...}

    //GET AppartmentCategory/2fdc968d-0192-e611-a98b-9c5c8e0005fa VIA ATTRIBUTE ROUTING    
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{propertyUid?}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetList(Guid propertyUid){...}
}
```

You should try to differentiate the two actions a little more and also try not to mix convention-based and attribute routing in the same controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("AppartmentCategory")]
public class AppartmentCategoryController : ApiController {
    //GET AppartmentCategory/043F61D1-7194-E611-A98B-9C5C8E0005FA
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{uid:guid}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid uid){...}

    //GET AppartmentCategory?propertyUid=2fdc968d-0192-e611-a98b-9c5c8e0005fa
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetList(Guid propertyUid){...}
}
```

Comment: Great thanks for explanation and resolution of my issue!